Making totals from two queries?
I am trying to calculate the space in a warehouse bin location.
I have the following data:
Table 1
Bin Location       Item      Quantity   Total Spots Used
000-A-006          ABC1      100        2
000-A-006          CDE1      200        4
000-B-001          A2EW      250        5

Table 2
Bin Location       Max Bin Capacity
000-A-006          25
000-B-001          15

I am looking for a simple one line total:
Quantity    Max Bin Capacity   Total Spots Used
550         40                 11

I cant just join the tables because bin 000-A-006 is listed twice, but I only want the 25 for table 2 to be totaled only once but need the total quantity and total spots used.
Thanks in advance.
I tried different different queries but I am getting multiple records in the output.

These should really just be two queries
 SELECT SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity, SUM(…), …
   FROM table1;

 SELECT SUM(MaxBinCapacity) AS MaxBinCapacity, … 
   FROM table2;

If you really need them in one result set, you could put the two queries into a UNION and add 0 fields:
 SELECT SUM(…), … FROM UNION ALL(
   SELECT …, 0 AS MaxBinCapacity FROM …
   SELECT …, 0 AS Quantity FROM …
 ) 


Sorry, I am not following this, when I did Union All, I got 2 different rows, I need just 1 row

Note, that there is an aggregation involved, which makes it one row.
